# MatLab 2009 installition isssue on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, matlab

Recently my university has started a course on MatLab. I have no pre-knowledge about this course as well as the software called MatLab! And All the computers in my universities computer lab runs on windows 7 and having MatLab 2009!

I searched for a couple of hours about the installation method of MatLab 2009 on Ubuntu 14.04 and got no complete instruction on it! Can anybody help me with complete instruction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the UNIX version of Matlab, you purchase it on mathworks website. You may be eligible for the student edition, which is cheaper. This is if you really want your own copy of Matlab, but if your uni provides you with computers with Matlab you can save on that and use computers at uni.
There is an opensource, free (you don't pay for it) software for ubuntu (and gnu/linux in general and other *nix systems) which has the same syntax and (basic) functionality as MATLAB. This software is called octave, you can have it on your system by opening a terminal emulator (press `Ctrl + Alt + t`) and type in `sudo apt-get install octave` and hit the enter key. Then type in your password, which won't show, neither as bullets nor as stars and hit the enter key. type in y and the enter key if asked for confirmation.
When your get a line which starts again with the dollar symbol $ type octave and the enter key and explore.

Comment: is there any cracked version of MatLab for ubuntu?

Comment: If what you're looking for is a pointer to a pirate copy of Matlab, it's obvious you're not going to get it on this website.

Comment: Oops! Sorry for that!

Comment: It might be your uni has a TAH agreement with Mathworks and you can download the student version of Matlab for free. You might check that.

Comment: Okay I am gonna check it out. And your suggestion `Octave` also helps me a lot.